# Inserting a text box into a usercontrol dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know in whether its possible to insert a textbox into an user control from the main .aspx page? If so how to do it? I'm a beginner in asp.net please help.

Comment: Can you please let us know what is exact scenario , why you need to add it dynamically since there are be other better solutions for it.

Comment: The scenario is i created a user control with 4 text boxes now i want it to be placed at two pages of .aspx .In First page its ok with 4 text boxes in the other i want to insert another text box into the same panel where the 4 text boxes are placed. So I need to place a text box inside user control from second .aspx page alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   TextBox tb1=new TextBox();
    tb1.ID="TbA";
    Uc1.Controls.Add(tb1);//here Uc1 is the Id of the userControl.Which is registered in .aspx file
```